# Do I need to do lua_pop each time after I do lua_setglobal?

Tags: lua

Just as the title mentioned, do I need to pop the value from the stack after I store it in the global space?

Comment: -1: The Lua documentation is very clear about how all of its functions affect the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to pop it. See [the documentation for `lua_setglobal`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_setglobal):

> Pops a value from the stack and sets it as the new value of global name.

Comment: @realjin: Also, on a side note, in the C-API reference all functions have this kind of info present: `[-0, +(0|1), m]` tells you the function does not pop stuff from the stack, and can push 0 or 1 elements, and can throw out-of-memory errors. See [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.7) for the complete explanation.